# What's a simple but secure method to get file contents into WordPress?

Tags: wp-filesystem, wp-remote-get

#### The scenario

I'm developing a plugin, and part of it requires lots of text content (help descriptions) that I would prefer to keep as separate text files (in a subdirectory within the plugin) for organisational and version control purposes. The obvious candidate would be `file_get_contents()`, but its usage with WordPress is generally frowned upon. I've looked at some alternatives, such as `wp_remote_get()` (not the right one as the files are *in* the plugin) and the `WP_Filesystem` API (which seems overkill for a simple reading of text files). **Is there a simple, but secure alternative?** I have the nagging feeling I'm missing something very obvious.

#### The spec

I'm looking for a solution to:

1. Read the contents of a HTML/text file into a variable
2. That won't flag as insecure when used with Theme Check or similar plugins
3. Doesn't require any writing to the files whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

I had to dig pretty deep for this too, and eventually figured out some way to do this.

in my solution I used the following:

```
WP_Filesystem();
global $wp_filesystem;
$wp_filesystem->exists( '/path/to/file' ); //use any other functions available in the Filesystem API: @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_filesystem_direct/
```

Comment: Looks promising; I'll definitely try this later this week. I originally avoided the `WP_Filesystem` API as it seemed more involved, but on closer inspection it looks easier than I originally thought.

Comment: Also worth noting that it is only available win the wp-admin context. It is not as easy to use in the frontend.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in your plugin file:

```
add_action('init', 'captureFileToVariable');

function captureFileToVariable(){
    $fileName = "FileIWantToLoad.txt";
    $pluginDirectory = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
    $filePath = $pluginDirectory . $fileName;
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($filePath);
    //die($fileContents);
}
```

Comment: One of the requirements was not raising any flags. Using wp_get_contents will get you this warning: "File operations should use WP_Filesystem methods instead of direct PHP filesystem calls. Found: file_get_contents()"